# its crashing while deleting the row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

in my table view class using following methods and I am trying to delete a row of the table view

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrUserData count];
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];   
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [arrUserData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

and i have some 40 rows in the table, when i click on the red delete button on any of the rows its crashing at this line

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

with the following crash log

```
2012-05-30 14:58:45.835 testDeleteRow[3276:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (41) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (41), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
```

can anyone tell me how can i fix this,,thanx in advance

Comment: don't you also have to delete that record form your data source?

Comment: try remove the object from the data source also [datasource removeobjectwith id];then delete it from table view you have because you are delete it from table view and the table view datasource sees that you still have the same numbers of rows...so delete object from datasource then delete it from table with animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to update your data source when you are deleting `cells`. If you are using an `array` for populating `table` then after this line -

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

you need to remove object at the same `index` from `array`. Also numbers of rows in `section` should be decrease by 1. if you are returning `array` count there then it will be automatically handle.

Comment: thanx for your reply,,now i am deleting the array element at the same index (pls check my edited question) but still its crashing,,

Comment: ys i fixed it just by deleting the datasource at that index , before deleting the Row

Answer (score 0):

When you delete row from tableview, your datasource does not get updated.Say if your table contain 10 rows before deletion, then after deletion it will contain only 9 rows, whereas your data source still contain 10 values.So you have to remove the deleted value from data source explicitly.

Comment: thanx for your reply,,now i am deleting the array element at the same index (pls check my edited question) but still its crashing,